# getting TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am getting the following error for the code

```
>TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
`<ipython-input-13-84f3963cacd1> in <module>()`

>          28 c = list(iris.columns.values)
         29 p = q-1
    ---> 30 X = iris.values(c[1:p])
         31 # y data
         32 y = iris.Species.values()

>TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I have already changed the code from as.matrix call to values call.

Comment: The error is self explanatory `iris.values` is not a function

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Supply code for your question. At least clarify which type is  `iris`?  Is `iris` `numpy.ndarray` ?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve as guide to improve your question. Help others to help you!

Comment: thanks exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want to achieve:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data #(150,4) numpy.ndarray
y = iris.target #(150, ) numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: @AnandTiwari If you find this answer helpful, please kindly consider accept it. :)